# Schedule scripts/jobs using azure cli

Tags: shell, powershell, azure, schedule, runbook

Does Microsoft azure give support to schedule scripts using az cli like it gives for Powershell runbooks on Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, Azure does **not** support to automation for AZ CLI.

Here a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/31482895-add-support-to-automation-for-az-cli) about it, you could vote up it, the feedback will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help:)